# C# Использование интерфейса, как обобщения, для метода

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Добрый день. Есть один метод сложения двух векторов, и мне в нём нужно, по заданию, поменять типы параметров таким образом, чтобы он работал со ссылками типа IVector. Код ниже - мои наработки по этому делу:

```
public static IVector Add(IVector v1, IVector v2)
    {
        if (v1.Length == v2.Length)
        {
            IVector v3 = v1;
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
            {
                v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
            }
            return v3;
        }
        else { throw new FormatException(); }
    }
```

Собственно проблема в том, что в оригинале метода перед циклом было создание нового экземпляра класса. С интерфейсом такого сделать нельзя и единственное, что мне пришло в голову - это приравнять новый объект к одному, который передавался в параметр. Но в таком случае изменяется и сам объект. С клонированием у меня что-то тоже не вышло, как я ни бился. Как тогда тут быть?

Comment: Может, тебе проще сделать public static  T Add<T>(T v1, Tv2) where T : IVector , new(){T v3= new T(); /*и так далее*/}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью `reflection` создать новый экземпляр типа `v1`.

```
Type type = v1.GetType();
ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new[] {});
IVector v3 = constructor.Invoke(new[] {});
```

В данном примере мы предполагаем что у класса `v1` есть конструктор без параметров, в противном случае можно выдавать ошибку, или продумать другую логику, например искать конструктор с компонентами вектора.

Подробнее про `reflection` [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.1.php).
Документация по функции `GetConstructor` [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Остаётся вопрос, насколько красиво вообще так делать. Дело в том, что сигнатура метода говорит о том что будет возвращён любой класс с интерфейсом `IVector`, с этой позиции можно смело возвратить любой класс, и не привязывать к первому вектору. Например `IVector v3 = new SimpleVector();` Но это некрасиво, так как странно если типы v1 и v2 совпадают, а возвращаемый тип совсем другой.

Но всё же это некрасивое решение, так как реально непонятно каким должен быть тип возвращаемого вектора, в особенности если типы v1 и v2 разные.

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону обобщенных `generic` методов.

```
public static T Add<T>(T v1, T v2) where T: IVector, new()
{ 
    if (v1.Length == v2.Length)
    {
        T v3 = new T();
        v3.Initialize(v1.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
        {
            v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
        }
        return v3;
    }
    else { throw new FormatException(); }
}
```

При таком подходе типы `v1` и `v2` должны совпадать.

Можно сделать другой вариант, задавать тип для возвращаемого вектора, и уже не привязываться к типам `v1` и `v2`.

```
public static T Add<T>(IVector v1, IVector v2) where T: IVector, new()
{
    if (v1.Length == v2.Length)
    {
        T v3 = new T();
        v3.Initialize(v1.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
        {
            v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
        }
        return v3;
    }
    else { throw new FormatException(); }
}
```

В данном случае у класса должен быть конструктор без параметров и у `IVector` функция `Initialize`. Это сделано так как в шаблонах нельзя делать `where T : new(int)`. Как альтернатива функцию которая создаёт вектор можно передавать параметрам в функцию `Add`.

```
public static IVector Add(Func<IVector,int> constructor, IVector v1, IVector v2)
```

В этом случае обошлись без обобщений.